# Remote JNDI-Lookup on JBoss 7.1 - Failed to connect to remote host

Tags: jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, jndi, connection-refused

I'm quite new to JavaEE and trying to get a little EJB example running, but always fail with the remote JNDI-Lookup.

What did I do until now?

1. I use Eclipse for JavaEE, installed JBossTools ffrom the Marketplace and created a JBoss EAP 7.x Runtime Server (I downloaded a 7.1 runtime during setup).
2. I wrote some Beans, deployed them on the server and started it.
3. I wrote some client code with a JNDI-Lookup

Here is the code:

HelloWorld.java

```
package com.ibytecode.business;  
import javax.ejb.Remote;  
@Remote  
public interface HelloWorld {  
    public String sayHello();  
}
```

HelloWorldBean.java

```
package com.ibytecode.businesslogic;  
import com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld;  
import javax.ejb.Stateless;  

@Stateless  
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorld {  
    public HelloWorldBean() { }  
    @Override  
    public String sayHello() {  
        return "Hello World !!!!!";  
    }  
}
```

EJBApplicationClient.java

```
package com.ibytecode.client;  
import java.util.Properties;  
import javax.naming.Context;  
import javax.naming.InitialContext;  
import javax.naming.NamingException;  
import com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld;  

public class EJBApplicationClient {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
          try {  
               Properties env = new Properties();  
               env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory.class.getName());  
               env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");  
               env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");  
               env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "admin");  
               InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(env);  
               ic.lookup("java:global/HelloWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean");  
          } catch (NamingException e) {  
               e.printStackTrace();  
          }
    }
}
```

Part of the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>16.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

And the server log when starting the JBoss server:

```
09:37:02,392 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.0.Final-redhat-1  
09:37:02,587 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1  
09:37:02,667 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) starting  
09:37:03,402 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.  
09:37:03,412 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.7.Final-redhat-1  
09:37:03,419 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 24) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.  
09:37:03,482 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found HelloWorldSessionBean.jar in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called HelloWorldSessionBean.jar.dodeploy  
09:37:03,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)  
09:37:03,512 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO version 3.5.4.Final-redhat-1  
09:37:03,518 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.5.4.Final-redhat-1  
09:37:03,534 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.  
09:37:03,539 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.0.24.Final-redhat-1  
09:37:03,541 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.  
09:37:03,541 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors  
09:37:03,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]  
09:37:03,553 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem  
09:37:03,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension  
09:37:03,559 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem  
09:37:03,580 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.18.Final-redhat-2 starting  
09:37:03,586 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final-redhat-1  
09:37:03,593 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)  
09:37:03,595 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.6.Final-redhat-1)  
09:37:03,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2  
09:37:03,608 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service  
09:37:03,613 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]  
09:37:03,638 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.5.Final-redhat-1  
09:37:03,709 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.  
09:37:03,709 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.  
09:37:03,725 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Users\sbh\jboss-eap-7.1/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']  
09:37:03,733 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.  
09:37:03,736 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting  
09:37:03,898 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080  
09:37:03,962 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYPAT0050: JBoss EAP cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none  
09:37:03,972 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Users\sbh\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost  
09:37:03,975 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\sbh\jboss-eap-7.1\standalone\deployments  
09:37:03,983 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "HelloWorldSessionBean.jar" (runtime-name: "HelloWorldSessionBean.jar")  
09:37:04,002 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443  
09:37:04,012 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete  
09:37:04,056 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.9.Final-redhat-1 (Apache CXF 3.1.12.redhat-1)   
09:37:04,059 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]  
09:37:04,168 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment HelloWorldSessionBean.jar  
09:37:04,194 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final-redhat-2  
09:37:04,238 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'HelloWorldBean' in deployment unit 'deployment "HelloWorldSessionBean.jar"' are as follows:  

    java:global/HelloWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld  
    java:app/HelloWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld  
    java:module/HelloWorldBean!com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld  
    java:jboss/exported/HelloWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld  
    java:global/HelloWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean  
    java:app/HelloWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean  
    java:module/HelloWorldBean  

09:37:04,335 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-2) WELD-000900: 2.4.3 (redhat)  
09:37:04,358 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final-redhat-1  
09:37:04,544 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container  
09:37:04,787 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "HelloWorldSessionBean.jar" (runtime-name : "HelloWorldSessionBean.jar")  
09:37:04,818 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server  
09:37:04,820 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management  
09:37:04,820 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990  
09:37:04,820 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) started in 2688ms - Started 408 of 632 services (350 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

So, I think the deployment of the bean and the Lookup-Name should be correct. But when I run the client application, I get this output:

```
Apr 11, 2019 9:40:38 AM org.wildfly.naming.client.Version   
INFO: WildFly Naming version 1.0.9.Final  
Apr 11, 2019 9:40:38 AM org.wildfly.security.Version   
INFO: ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.7.Final-redhat-1  
Apr 11, 2019 9:40:38 AM org.xnio.Xnio   
INFO: XNIO version 3.6.5.Final  
Apr 11, 2019 9:40:38 AM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio   
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.6.5.Final  
Apr 11, 2019 9:40:38 AM org.jboss.threads.Version   
INFO: JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final  
Apr 11, 2019 9:40:38 AM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl   
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 5.0.8.Final  
javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information]  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNaming(RemoteNamingProvider.java:110)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNaming(RemoteNamingProvider.java:53)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNamingUsingRetry(NamingProvider.java:105)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNamingUsingRetry(RemoteNamingProvider.java:91)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lambda$lookupNative$0(RemoteContext.java:189)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.NamingProvider.performExceptionAction(NamingProvider.java:222)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.performWithRetry(RemoteContext.java:100)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteContext.lookupNative(RemoteContext.java:188)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:74)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.AbstractFederatingContext.lookup(AbstractFederatingContext.java:60)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyRootContext.lookup(WildFlyRootContext.java:144)  
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)  
    at com.ibytecode.client.EJBApplicationClient.testRemoteJNDILookup(EJBApplicationClient.java:27)  
    at com.ibytecode.client.EJBApplicationClient.main(EJBApplicationClient.java:16)  
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information  
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)  
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread$ConnectHandle.handleReady(WorkerThread.java:327)  
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)  
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)  
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:571)  
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:537)  
    at org.jboss.remoting3.ConnectionInfo$None.getConnection(ConnectionInfo.java:82)  
    at org.jboss.remoting3.ConnectionInfo.getConnection(ConnectionInfo.java:55)  
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doGetConnection(EndpointImpl.java:488)  
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.getConnectedIdentity(EndpointImpl.java:434)  
    at org.jboss.remoting3.UncloseableEndpoint.getConnectedIdentity(UncloseableEndpoint.java:52)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getFuturePeerIdentityPrivileged(RemoteNamingProvider.java:151)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.lambda$getFuturePeerIdentity$0(RemoteNamingProvider.java:138)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getFuturePeerIdentity(RemoteNamingProvider.java:138)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentity(RemoteNamingProvider.java:126)  
    at org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteNamingProvider.getPeerIdentityForNaming(RemoteNamingProvider.java:106)  
    ... 13 more
```

I guess I am just missing some simple configuration.
Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have working client code with a JNDI-Lookup. The only thing is that it is for jBoss EAP 6.4, not for jBoss EAP 7.1.  In case you use correct application user credentials, suppose it is enough to change `ic.lookup("java:global/HelloWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean");`

to

`ic.lookup("HelloWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean");`

in your code.
Below is my working example

```
private static RepFormsEJBRemote lookupRemoteEJB() throws NamingException {
    RepFormsEJBRemote rf;
    Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
    jndiProperties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
    jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://172.21.0.12:4447");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jmsuser"); //
    jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "qwertyasd34,");  // 
    final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
    rf = (RepFormsEJBRemote) context.lookup("ModuleEAR/ModuleWar/RepFormsEJB!com.somename.interfaces.RepFormsEJBRemote");
    return rf;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, but I still get the same `Connection refused` error. I think the problem may be  with the server configuration to allow remote connections at all.

Comment: Did you try to check port availability by command "telnet localhost 4447" ?

Comment: That might be the problem. How can I tell the JBoss AS to actually using the remoting port 4447?

Comment: In case of jBoss EAP 6.4 remoting port may be indicated in config file standalone-full.xml (or any other used) in section socket-binding-group as <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>. But it may be indicated as parameter for jBoss service launch.

Answer (score 0):

`Hello`,

For JBoss EAP 7.1 the lockup changed completely and Alister's answer **only applies to JBoss EAP 6.4**.

This is the lookup for **JBoss EAP 7.1:** is then:

```
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote+http://localhost:8080");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "adm");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "adm");
```

Highlight that `Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY` changed to `org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory` in JBoss EAP 7.1

Your lookup will be (for example):

```
SumRemote remote = (SumRemote) getInitialContext().lookup("ejb:/EjbSum/Sum!SumRemote");
```

You can see it on the logs when JBoss EAP starts:

```
03:12:20,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'Sum' in deployment unit 'deployment "EjbSum.jar"' are as follows:

    java:global/EjbSum/Sum!SumRemote
    java:app/EjbSum/Sum!SumRemote
    java:module/Sum!SumRemote
    java:jboss/exported/EjbSum/Sum!SumRemote
    ejb:/EjbSum/Sum!SumRemote
    java:global/EjbSum/Sum
    java:app/EjbSum/Sum
    java:module/Sum
```